# Radpanelbar scroll issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, c#-4.0, telerik

I have scroll issue of Telerik control RadPanelBar. Page is on auto refresh. On page refresh RadPanelBar scroll goes upward. I handle this with JavaScript. Below is the image.

[image]

Below is the code. Its working fine for dealers contacts scroll, but not for staff. I am trying the same way(method) to maintain scroll position for staff.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(".rpSlide ul").scroll(function() { 
       SaveStafftScrollPosition();            
   });

   function SaveStaffScrollPosition(){
       yPos = $(".rpSlide ul").scrollTop();        
   }

   function ReturnStaffScrollPosition() {
       $(".rpSlide ul").scrollTop(yPos);        
   }

   function OnResponseEnd(sender ,eventArgs){
       ReturnStaffScrollPosition();
   }

   function OnRequestStart(sender ,eventArgs){
       SaveStafftScrollPosition();
   }
```

In HTML having piece of code.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1"  runat="server"
         ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="OnRequestStart" 
         ClientEvents-OnResponseEnd="OnResponseEnd" 
         OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest">
    //some code here
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Problem is this it saved scroll position zero for staff when i scroll down.
Why it always saved scroll position to zero for staff contacts even i scroll down to middle/end?

Comment: Do Dealers and Staff lists share the `rpSlide` css class? I guess that you save only scrollTop of the Dealers ul.

Comment: No they're not sharing. And i am saving scrollTop for Deaelrs with same way but having different id in $("for dealers").

Comment: So, dealers ul's container doesn't has `.rpSlide` class? Try to execute in browsers console this code `$(".rpSlide ul").length` and check returned value

Comment: Yes. Dealer's using `.rpGroup` class. And its returning value zero.

Comment: Then fix selector to get your list

Comment: Thanks @YuriyRozhovetskiy, i am trying my best!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` property of your `@Page` tag and setting the `AutoEventWireup` property to `false`?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="YourPage.aspx.vb"
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Inherits="YourPageClass" %>
```

> **MSDN Documentation**
>
> ***AutoEventWireup***
>
> Indicates whether the page's events are autowired.
>   true if event autowiring is enabled; otherwise, false. The default is
>   true. For more information, see ASP.NET Web Server Control Event
>   Model.
>
> ***MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback***
>
> Indicates whether to return the user
>   to the same position in the client browser after postback. true if
>   users should be returned to the same position; otherwise, false. The
>   default is false.
>
> *Note* : Developers can define this attribute for all pages by setting
>   the maintainScrollPostitionOnPostback attribute (note that it is
>   case-sensitive in configuration files) on the  element of the
>   Web.config file.